# How to highlight code on a webpage when you’re using Markdown

Tags: django, tinymce, markdown, highlight

I want to use [highlighted.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) also I have grappelli and tinymce. I want to add highlighted.js but I have markdown editor.

How can I add highlighted.js while I am using markdown editor?

Answer (score 0):

HTML is valid markdown, you should simply insert the link tag as you would with HTML.